# Remove space in string isn't working

Tags: string, swift

I am trying to delete Spaces in `Strings`, which are phone numbers from the contacts app.

My code is working fine for most of the numbers, but for 2 it doesn't work. It doesn't recognize the space, even though they are in the exact same format as the others.

E.g.: if `y = +49 999 99999999` then `phonenumber = 0 999 99999999`, but it should be `099999999999`.

```
let x = number[i].value as! CNPhoneNumber
let y = x.stringValue

// let toArray = y.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
// let string = toArray.joinWithSeparator("")

var o = y.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
o = o.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+49", withString: "0")
o = o.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString: "")
o = o.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")
o = o.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
phonenumber = o
```

Comment: Just a note: nothing in there will remove the leading `0`.

Comment: So maybe it is not a space after all, but something like a fixed space. Check your input strings.

Comment: Yes, i forgot the 0. It should stay. @Jongware what do you mean with fixed space

Comment: Print out the ASCII values of all characters in that string.

Comment: @Jongware when it's working, the space is Ascii 32 and when it's not working, it's value nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks it is working.

Your code

```
let y = "+49 999 99999999"
var o = y.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
o = o.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+49", withString: "0")
o = o.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString: "")
o = o.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")
o = o.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
print(o, terminator:"")
```

actually does print:

```
099999999999
```

What is the type of variable `phonenumber`? Maybe it's the reason why you see 2 spaces added.

### Update

Since the problem seems related to bad ascii values you could apply the inverse approach. Now you are specifying what to **remove**, try to specify what to **keep**.

```
let digits : Set<Character> = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let phoneNumberWithPrefixAndSpaces = "+49 157 77859770"
let phoneNumbersWithSpaces = phoneNumberWithPrefixAndSpaces.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+49", withString: "0")
// only digits will "survive" to the next instruction
var phoneNumber = String(phoneNumbersWithSpaces.characters.filter { digits.contains($0) })
print(phoneNumber, terminator:"")
```

Comment: It is a String, and it is working for some numbers, for example: "+49 176 92621857", but it isn't working for "+49 157 77859770". The number is the String value of a CNPhoneNumber from a Contact

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs: So the type of the variable `phonenumber` is `String`?

Comment: Yes, the type of phone number is String

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs: I tested your code with the input `+49 157 77859770` and the output is correct: `015777859770`. No spaces. How are you checking the result? Are you printing it to the console? Or are you populating some GUI element?

Comment: I am checking it with breakpoints. It is working for you, because you are setting it as a new String. I am getting the value from my dress book, and the problem is that the spaces are apparently no spaces, because they have no ascii code.Apparently the string is broken but i don't know why

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs: understood, please take a look at my updated answer.